# Saving data to database using linq

Tags: c#, linq, combobox, textbox

I face problems with my codes about saving data into database. I have a Text box and a Combo box but when I key in data in the Text box and select data in the Combo box and click save, nothing happens and no error were found during compiling. Can I know what actually went wrong and give me some solution to it?

```
enter code here  private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            string selectST = cbSeats.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string inputST = txtStation.Text;

            var createStation = (from createST in Setupctx.stations
                                  where createST.Seats == selectST
                                  where createST.Station1 == inputST
                                  select createST).SingleOrDefault();
            if (createStation != null)
            {
                Setupctx.stations.AddObject(createStation);
                Setupctx.SaveChanges();
                txtStation.Text = "";

                MessageBox.Show("New Station Has Been Created.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to update the "createStation" or create a new station?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right way of doing it.

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            string[] stations = StationNameList();
            station creStation = new station();
            creStation.Station1 = txtStation.Text;
            creStation.Seats = cbSeats.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (stations.Contains(txtStation.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This Station is already been created. Please enter a new Station.");
            }
            else
            {
                Setupctx.stations.AddObject(creStation);
                Setupctx.SaveChanges();
                txtStation.Text = "";
                cbSeats.SelectedIndex = -1;
                MessageBox.Show("New Station Has Been Created.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm agreeing with @JamesD on making sure the event handler is called.

Additionally, when you get an object from a linq query and make changes to it, you need to save those changes it by calling SubmitChanges() on the DataContext. (I'm assuming that Setupctx is a DataContext object).

Read here for information on [SubmitChanges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.submitchanges.aspx)

Also, I don't know if you are using SQL or not. If so, here is a great tutorial: [Linq to SQL Tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new station object like this:

```
    if (createStation != null)
  {
    var obj = new Staion();
    obj.Seats=selectST;
    obj.Staion1=inputST;


    Setupctx.Staions.Add(obj);
    Setupctx.SubmitChanges();

    txtStation.Text = "";

     MessageBox.Show("New Station Has Been Created.");
}
```

More on [LINQ To SQL here](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LinqToSQL5MinuteOVerview.ashx)

Answer (score 0):

Just to check off the list:

- Have you made sure the button event handler is hooked up?

When you say

> nothing happens

Do you mean the event handler is not called? You're not actually doing anything with the station you've retrieved from the database either. You're adding it back in to the stations list that you've pulled it out from.

Comment: Meaning my select statement is wrong? How do I going to do that since I want to add into my database by keying Text in the Text box and select value from the combo box. Any solution?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify what your code is supposed to be doing with some inline comments in the code